# Not able to run java code in Visual Studio Code

Tags: java, visual-studio-code, java-8, vscode-debugger

[image: Error]

I installed all the extension of java and provided path in environment variable. Still no output is generating as shown in image. What should i do?

Comment: Have you restarted VSC after installing extensions?

Comment: Your class is named `Hello` (not `Solution`). And you have a method `name`, not the entry-point `main`. And unless you're writing some kind of software for the Raspberry Pi, I think you meant "competitive" (not "Compititive").

Answer (score 0):

You defined a class but you have not instantiated and execute the code. Write a main function as the entry point. In the main function, create a new instance and then invoke the `name` function.

BTW, the best practice for Java is to name a class after noun and a function after verb, or start the function name with a verb. It will make more sense to name the class `Name` and the function `sayHello`.